# Orange 3 : distant GUI

Tags: orange

I would like to use Orange3 for making analysing on BigData. Of course I have to put Orange and the DB on the same computer, that I would like to access via web (from another machine). I also would like to give the access to many people.
Is there a way to use Orange3 interface via a web interface ? And to open several Orange3 interfaces on the same server ?

Thanks,
Best,
mike

Answer (score 0):

Albeit it does support multiple platforms, Orange looks like a single desktop application which does *not* imlement a client-server architecture and can't be run in a web browser (it uses Qt).

Without other third-party remote-desktop tools, like various RDP clients, ssh+X11, LogMeIn, TeamViewer etc., my guess is you're out of luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. If I have a brilliant idea, I let you know :).